# Failed to execute goal on project.. Failed to read artifact descriptor for error in IntellJ

Tags: java, maven, build, installation

[image]

I imported my project and when did a maven clean build was successful, but when maven install is done this Build Failure occurs.
I have my maven in C\maven\maven 3.6 and I have given the settings and repo location of that location to this project. [image]

My Env variables are correctly set up with reference to Java and Maven as well. Please help me on this to get it solved.

Comment: Access is denied on one of the lock files. You could try removing that one file. Or clearing all of your local maven repo.

Comment: Thank you, but when I check in the folder there is no file in that name

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of the proxy ! Check you proxy and test if it's working.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the proxy connection but it is successful

Comment: I have just seen you log error message, the access to your nexus is denied ! so it is an access problem to your nexus.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was thinking that is the issue. But other team members also have the same access. Working on it, will update if this is an access problem.